# could not be authenticated to presence-chats-channel (Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403) Laravel Echo Server

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo, echo-server

Everything was working fine but when i try to run

```
laravel-echo-server start
```

from supervisor below error appear.

```
[11:25:15 PM] - zmMtehwMctWVHxFBAAAB joined channel: chats-channel
[11:25:16 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: https://test.net
[11:25:16 PM] - Sending auth request to: https://test.net/broadcasting/auth

⚠ [11:25:16 PM] - zmMtehwMctWVHxFBAAAB could not be authenticated to presence-chats-channel

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the below code from the vue component.

```
Echo.join(chat.${roomId})
.here((users) => {
//
})
.joining((user) => {
console.log(user.name);
})
.leaving((user) => {
console.log(user.name);
});
```